# Get Data from a table which has been generated programmatically

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a Control Table programmatically and I want after user clicks a button to get the values.

The table has three columns, {Title(*DropDownList*), FName(*TextBox*), LName(*TextBox*)} and two rows.

I am getting the values for FName, LName without problem, but I am getting wrong value for Title, which is a DropDownList. It gives me for both Titles, the selected value of the second column.

**More Clear,**

For the 1st row --> Mr, Foo, Bar

for 2nd row- -> Mrs, Foo, Bar

**after user clicks the button I am getting**

For 1st row --> **Mrs**, Foo, Bar

For 2nd row- -> Mrs, Foo1, Bar.

This is the method of table creation

```
private void SetPassengerDetailsTable(int roomIdentity, int? adults,
        int? children, int? infants, bool setLeader = false) {
        var leaderIsSet = false;
        var roomTable = new Table();
        roomTable.ID = "PassengerDetailsTBL_" + roomIdentity;
        var trHeader = new TableHeaderRow();
        var tcTitle = new TableCell();
        tcTitle.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "<b>Title</b>" });
        trHeader.Cells.Add(tcTitle);

        var tcFName = new TableCell();
        tcFName.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "<b>First Name</b>" });
        trHeader.Cells.Add(tcFName);

        var tcLName = new TableCell();
        tcLName.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "<b>Last Name</b>" });
        trHeader.Cells.Add(tcLName);

        var tcType = new TableCell();
        tcType.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "<bType</b>" });
        trHeader.Cells.Add(tcType);

        roomTable.Rows.Add(trHeader);

        var listItems = new ListItem[6];
        listItems[0] = new ListItem("", "") { Selected = true };
        listItems[1] = new ListItem("Mr", "Mr");
        listItems[2] = new ListItem("Mrs", "Mrs");
        listItems[3] = new ListItem("Miss", "Miss");
        listItems[4] = new ListItem("Infant", "Inf");
        listItems[5] = new ListItem("Child", "Master");


        if (adults != null || adults > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= adults; i++) {
                var trBody = new TableRow();
                var ddl = new DropDownList();
                var leadAdultRowID = setLeader && !leaderIsSet ? "leadadult" : "adult";
                ddl.ID = "room" + roomIdentity + leadAdultRowID + i + "Title";
                ddl.Items.AddRange(listItems);

                var tcTitleValue = new TableCell();
                tcTitleValue.Controls.Add(ddl);
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcTitleValue);

                var tcFNameValue = new TableCell();
                tcFNameValue.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "room" + roomIdentity + "adult" + i + "FName", Width = 170 });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcFNameValue);

                var tcLNameValue = new TableCell();
                tcLNameValue.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "room" + roomIdentity + "adult" + i + "LName", Width = 170 });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcLNameValue);

                var tcTypeValue = new TableCell();
                var leadAdult = setLeader && !leaderIsSet ? "Lead Adult" : "Adult";
                tcTypeValue.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = leadAdult });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcTypeValue);
                roomTable.Rows.Add(trBody);

                if (setLeader)
                    leaderIsSet = true;
            }
        }

        if (children != null || children > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= children; i++) {
                var trBody = new TableRow();
                var ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "room" + roomIdentity + "child" + i + "Title";
                ddl.Items.AddRange(listItems);

                var tcTitleValue = new TableCell();
                tcTitleValue.Controls.Add(ddl);
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcTitleValue);

                var tcFNameValue = new TableCell();
                tcFNameValue.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "room" + roomIdentity + "child" + i + "FName", Width = 170 });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcFNameValue);

                var tcLNameValue = new TableCell();
                tcLNameValue.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "room" + roomIdentity + "child" + i + "LName", Width = 170 });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcLNameValue);

                var tcTypeValue = new TableCell();
                tcTypeValue.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Child" });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcTypeValue);
                roomTable.Rows.Add(trBody);
            }
        }

        if (infants != null || infants > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= infants; i++) {
                var trBody = new TableRow();
                var ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "room" + roomIdentity + "infan" + i + "Title";
                ddl.Items.AddRange(listItems);

                var tcTitleValue = new TableCell();
                tcTitleValue.Controls.Add(ddl);
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcTitleValue);

                var tcFNameValue = new TableCell();
                tcFNameValue.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "room" + roomIdentity + "infan" + i + "FName", Width = 170 });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcFNameValue);

                var tcLNameValue = new TableCell();
                tcLNameValue.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "room" + roomIdentity + "infan" + i + "LName", Width = 170 });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcLNameValue);

                var tcTypeValue = new TableCell();
                tcTypeValue.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Infant" });
                trBody.Cells.Add(tcTypeValue);
                roomTable.Rows.Add(trBody);
            }
        }
        PassengerDetailsPH.Controls.Add(roomTable);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new listItems list for every instance of the DropDownList

```
var ddlItems = listItems.ToArray();

ddl.Items.Addrange(ddlItems);
```

(have you looked at the GridView control?)

Comment: I will try this. Yes I know the GridView control but I have been stached with this and I want to solve it. If not, then I will do this with GridView.

Answer (score 1):

Double check what client-side IDs are generated for your drop downs.

If you table is rendered correctly (with correct IDs which must be unique), then the code which reads is reading from the wrong  element.

Comment: I checked it and the IDs are unique. Was the first thought it came in my mind

Comment: If you're rebuilding the table on each post-back, that would cause a problem. Debug through reading code and check if the correct element IDs are being read. I'm assuming that regular postback preserves values selected in all controls and doesn't modify any controls.